# Нижняя панель наезжает на контент

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:background="@color/colorGrayBackround"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Делаю свою кастомную нижнюю панель в виде вложенного `LinearLayout`. При данной верстке она накладывается на нижние элементы `RecyclerView`. Как исправить?

Хочу сделать поведение как на вкладке музыка в ВК:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы кастомный бар не накладывался на контент и нижняя панель с музыкой тоже. Полагаю, что тут дело в `app:layout_behavior`. Значение `"@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` дает только поведение с баром. А как добавить к этому поведению работу с нижней панелью музыки?

Comment: Насколько я понял, тут проблема CollapsingToolbarLayout и флага app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: То есть вы хотите фиксированный бар и панель? Чтобы при прокрутке списка они никуда не девались?

Comment: @Flippy нет, привел не очень хороший пример. На вкладке музыка в вк вверху над табами есть бар с поиском, он скролится при прокрутке вверх. А нижняя панель с музыкой фиксированная. Я хочу также, чтобы бар скролился, для этого поставил флаг в CollapsingToolbarLayout app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed", а нижняя панель была фиксирована.

Comment: @Flippy Проблем с фиксированным баром и панелью нет – в CollapsingToolbarLayout поставить флаг app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways", контент обернуть в RelativeLayout, в котором привязать нижнюю панель к нижней части экрана, а RecyclerView разместить над панелью. Но если при такой обертке вернуть флаг CollapsingToolbarLayout в положении "scroll", получим не ту картину.